# C# perform method after delay

Tags: c#

I want to create a method that receives a method as a parameter and delay var. And execute the method after delay:

```
    public static void performSelectorAfterDelay<T>(Action<T> method, T parameter, double delay)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(delegate()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(delay));
            uc.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => method(parameter)));
        });
        thread.Start();
    }
```

I want it to be Generic so i will be able to call it for these two methods:

```
    public void funcA()
    {

    }

    public void funcB(int num)
    {

    }
```

When i call it:

```
performSelectorAfterDelay(new Action(funcA), null, kSecondsWaitAfterTransferToFollowersPage);
performSelectorAfterDelay(new Action(funcB), 5, kSecondsWaitAfterTransferToFollowersPage);
```

I get this error:

> The type arguments for method performSelectorAfterDelay(System.Action, T, double)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Any idea what can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler can't work out the type, because you're passing null as the 2nd parameter.

```
performSelectorAfterDelay(new Action(funcA), null, kSecondsWaitAfterTransferToFollowersPage);
```

Anyway, after you resolve that issue you will end up with another error, because `funcB` takes an `int`, so it cannot be passed into `new Action` because `Action` requires a parameterless method.

You may be able to get it working using `Action<object>` as per the other answer, but that will mean you can't leave `funcA` without a parameter. However, this solution seems redundant to me unless I'm misunderstanding something. You can just pass an actual Action that calls funcA/funcB with their parameters like so:

```
public void performSelectorAfterDelay(Action method, double delay)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(delegate ()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(delay));
        method();
    });
    thread.Start();
}

public void test()
{
    performSelectorAfterDelay(() => funcA(), kSecondsWaitAfterTransferToFollowersPage);
    performSelectorAfterDelay(() => funcB(1), kSecondsWaitAfterTransferToFollowersPage);
}
```

Comment: _"funcB takes an int, so it cannot be used as an Action"_ - not sure what you mean there? `Action<int>` has one parameter of type int, and doesn't return a value..

Comment: @stuartd `new Action` requires a `void()`. I've tried to explain it better - first post on SO in ages.

Comment: Ah I get you now. I missed that OP was using `new Action(funcA)` and assumed OP would just pass `funcA`, Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells something.
Here is the fixed version sir:

```
    public static void funcA(object obj)
    {
    }

    public static void funcB(int num)
    {
    }

    public static void performSelectorAfterDelay<T>(Action<T> method, T parameter, double delay)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(delegate()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(delay));
            uc.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => method(parameter)));
        });
        thread.Start();
    }

    public static void SomeCall()
    {
        performSelectorAfterDelay(new Action<object>(funcA), null, kSecondsWaitAfterTransferToFollowersPage);
        performSelectorAfterDelay(new Action<int>(funcB), 5, kSecondsWaitAfterTransferToFollowersPage);
    }
```

Comment: This will work, but it means you'll never be able to use a parameterless method. `funcA` in the OPs example would need modifying to take an object just to be able to pass null to it.

Comment: Yes you are right, I know it, it is just an alternative solution for the user.